# Android force close problem?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm having a bit of trouble with my Android app.
The application seems to force close whenever I put in:

```
String fileContents = getFileContents("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+code);
    fileContents = fileContents.substring(fileContents.indexOf("\'VIDEO_ID\': "+"\""+code+"\""),fileContents.indexOf("yt.setMsg({"));
    String[] settings = fileContents.split("fmt_url_map");
    settings = settings[settings.length-1].split("\"");
    String map = settings[2];
    map = map.replace("\\/", "/").replace("\\u0026", "&");
    fmtMap = map.split("[,|]+");
    hash = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    for(int i = 0; i< fmtMap.length/2; i ++) {
        hash.put(new Integer(Integer.parseInt(fmtMap[2*i])),fmtMap[2*i+1]);
    }
```

My getFileContents() function is:

```
public static String getFileContents(String path) {
    InputStreamReader instream = null;
    URL url = null;
    URLConnection urlConn = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(path);
        try {
            urlConn = url.openConnection();
            instream = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(instream);
        try {
            String line = null;
            while((line = f.readLine()) != null) {
                contents.append(line);
                contents.append(separator);
            }
        }
        finally {
            f.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
    String text = contents.toString();
    return text;
}
```

I suspect it's not working because I copied this directly from one of my Java projects, but I don't understand why.

If anybody can help, that would be great!
:D

Comment: The best help anyone can give you at this point is to tell you to post the logcat output.

Comment: you probably didn't add the internet permission to your manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first needed to add the following line in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

After adding this line, the `getFileContents(String path)` method returned an HTML string.

The `fileContents.substring` call throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` on this line:

```
fileContents = fileContents.substring(fileContents.indexOf("\'VIDEO_ID\':     "+"\""+code+"\""),fileContents.indexOf("yt.setMsg({"));
```

The expression `fileContents.indexOf("yt.setMsg({")` returns **-1**, and it's likely the other `indexOf` call is also returning **-1**.

To diagnose these problems [Logcat is your best friend!](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out.
Turns out, when I was querying the website, YouTube was giving me their mobile version of the site. I just had to add a &nomobile=1 to the URL.
Thanks anyways, though.